# Load word2vec dictionary into gensim

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, spacy, word-embedding

I've loaded pretrained word2vec embeddings into a python dictionary of the form

`{word: vector}`

As an example, an element of this dictionary is

`w2v_dict["house"] = [1.1,2.0, ... , 0.2]`

I would like to load this model into Gensim (or a similar library) so that I can find euclidean distances between embeddings.

I understand that pretrained embeddings typically come in a .bin file which can be loaded into Gensim. But if I only have a dictionary of this form, how would I load the vectors into a model?

Answer (score 0):

Usually pre-trained word-vectors come in a format `gensim` could natively read, for example via the `load_word2vec_format()` method. It's atypical that you only have vectors in your own format.

So, I'd recommend writing your vectors to a text format compatible with other word2vec libraries You can review `gensim`'s `save_word2vec_format()` method at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/9819ce828b9ed7952f5d96cbb12fd06bbf5de3a3/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py#L131

You could also train up a dummy `Word2Vec` model with any junk/toy data, save its vectors in the text format (`w2v_model.wv.save_word2vec_format(filename, binary=False)`), and review the resulting file.

Using the above source code or example file, write your dictionary in a similar format. Then, use gensim's `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename)` to read your vectors in.

Comment: Could you solve this? I'm struggling with the same thing.

Comment: Solve what, exactly? Are your word-vectors in the same non-standard format as the original question asker? What's inadequate about the suggestions already provided?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was able to reverse engineer the structure of the Gensim expected file and then output my embeddings file in the same format and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as gensim word2vec format then load it with `gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format`.Details [here](https://www.kaggle.com/matsuik/convert-embedding-dictionary-to-gensim-w2v-format).